# IntegrityError at /accounts/register/ null value in column "activated" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-registration

This error is showing when I try to register using django-registration-redux.I removed totally the database and the old migrations, but after deploying on heroku it gives me this strange error:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/register/

null value in column "activated" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 008bf2bb5fa9425aaa6c4828167e7221fc873660, 1, null).
```

Every time I do a new migration, appears the same:

```
   0004_remove_registrationprofile_activated.py:
    - Remove field activated from registrationprofile
```

Where should I look for the error? Why it appeared so unexpected ?

Comment: Show us the model of the profile!

Comment: I am using django-registration-redux. So everything, including the model of the profile is out of the box.